# How to create a ternary (or any-ary) diagram in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create some ternary colour map diagram

Something along the line of [**this**](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Ternary-diagram-and-relative-abundance-of-potassium-uranium-and-thorium_fig7_273168612)
[image]
and
[**this**](https://theunsavourypipe.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/spatialplot_rgb.jpg) 
[image]- in `python`.

I have read at `plt.legend()` command in `matplotlib`, but couldn't find a way to accomplish such.

Any recommendation on potential framework/workaround that I could go and play with?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been using [this](https://github.com/marcharper/python-ternary) library.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I what - it looks like it created a ternary graph - rather than creating a ternary diagram where the colour legend is triangular, and the values of the dots/pixel on the map shows the magnitude.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not a ternary diagram, it is a ternary radiometric image or map. The authors of the paper you refer to it as such in the Materials and Methods sections and the paper referees have not done a great job enforcing this term in the rest of the paper. By the way, the radiometric image has been created using Oasis Montaj. You could probably DIY such an image by specifying the RGB channels of the map as the fraction of each element on a 1 to 255 scale.